# TextView and Double Text View. Why can't I call these coordinates?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call coordinates when a button is pressed and have my map go to those coordinates. However, every time I try to change this to a double or a string, I get a new error. Code:

```
private void updateLocationUI() {
    if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f", mLatitudeLabel,
                mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f", mLongitudeLabel,
                mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
        mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText("Date/Time:"+ " " + currentDateandTime);
        
        LatLng maryland = new LatLng(mLatitudeTextView, mLongitudeTextView);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(maryland));
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(8.0f);

        }
    }
```

The part that doesn't work is the mLatitudeTextView and mLongitudeTextView. Any ideas?

Comment: *I get a new error.* What is that error please clarify us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
private void updateLocationUI() {
    if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f", mLatitudeLabel,
                mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f", mLongitudeLabel,
                mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
        mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText("Date/Time:"+ " " + currentDateandTime);
        
        LatLng maryland = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),  mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(maryland));
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(8.0f);

        }
    }
```

I am assuming `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude(`) returns double

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
LatLng maryland = new LatLng(mLatitudeTextView, mLongitudeTextView)
```

To:

```
LatLng maryland = new LatLng(        Double.parseDouble(mLatitudeTextView.getText().toString()), Double.parseDouble(mLongitudeTextView.getText().toString()))
```

Comment: error: incompatible types: CharSequence cannot be converted to double

Comment: Double.parseDouble(mLatitudeTextView.getText().toString()), Double.parseDouble(mLongitudeTextView.getText().toString())